# Function Returning Wrong Data

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue with the mentioned procedure code that does not return actual data also giving error #1172 - Result consisted of more than one row. More ever if I use to limit or distinct in the query it is also giving me the wrong result. Please help me to correct my code. Below given table from which I want to get data via function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION get_program_target1(  
    ACT_T_NUM INT  
)   
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)  
DETERMINISTIC  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE A_ID INT;  
    SELECT  A1.tot_ann_trai  INTO   A_ID
  FROM   budget A1
  WHERE  A1.trai_activity_type = ACT_T_NUM;
  
  RETURN A_ID;

END$$
DELIMITER
;
```

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
| budget_fy |             trai_activity_type              | trai_activity_type_id | tot_tari_budg |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
| 2020-21   | Inhouse T-Desk - Physical                   |                     5 |        540000 |
| 2020-21   | Inhouse T-Desk - Physical                   |                     5 |        420000 |
| 2020-21   | Inhouse T-Desk - Physical                   |                     5 |        210000 |
| 2020-21   | Inhouse T-Desk - Physical                   |                     5 |        120000 |
| 2020-21   | Outsource T-Desk                            |                     6 |        123750 |
| 2020-21   | Outsource T-Desk                            |                     6 |        123750 |
| 2020-21   | Outsource T-Desk                            |                     6 |        247500 |
| 2020-21   | Outsource T-Desk                            |                     6 |        495000 |
| 2020-21   | In-House Training Program - Physical        |                     1 |       2520000 |
| 2020-21   | In-House Training Program - Physical        |                     1 |       1590000 |
| 2020-21   | In-House Training Program - Physical        |                     1 |       1260000 |
| 2020-21   | In-House Training Program - Physical        |                     1 |        960000 |
| 2020-21   | Training of Trainers (TOT) / BDSP Trainings |                     7 |       1090000 |
| 2020-21   | Training of Trainers (TOT) / BDSP Trainings |                     7 |       1100000 |
| 2020-21   | Training of Trainers (TOT) / BDSP Trainings |                     7 |        600000 |
| 2020-21   | Training of Trainers (TOT) / BDSP Trainings |                     7 |        710000 |
| 2020-21   | Inhouse T-Desk Online                       |                     4 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | Youth Entrepreneurship Program              |                     2 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | Youth Entrepreneurship Program              |                     2 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | Youth Entrepreneurship Program              |                     2 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | Youth Entrepreneurship Program              |                     2 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | Inhouse T-Desk Online                       |                     4 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | In-House Training Program - Online          |                     8 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | In-House Training Program - Online          |                     8 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | In-House Training Program - Online          |                     8 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | In-House Training Program - Online          |                     8 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | Inhouse T-Desk Online                       |                     4 |             0 |
| 2020-21   | Inhouse T-Desk Online                       |                     4 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | Sector Specific Trainings- Three Day        |                    15 |       2153250 |
| 2021-22   | Sector Specific Trainings- Three Day        |                    15 |       7177500 |
| 2021-22   | Sector Specific Trainings- Three Day        |                    15 |       4306500 |
| 2021-22   | Sector Specific Trainings- Three Day        |                    15 |        717750 |
| 2021-22   | Inhouse T-Desk - Physical                   |                     5 |        270000 |
| 2021-22   | Inhouse T-Desk - Physical                   |                     5 |         90000 |
| 2021-22   | Inhouse T-Desk - Physical                   |                     5 |         75000 |
| 2021-22   | Inhouse T-Desk - Physical                   |                     5 |         45000 |
| 2021-22   | Theme Specific Trainings                    |                     9 |        500000 |
| 2021-22   | Theme Specific Trainings                    |                     9 |       1500000 |
| 2021-22   | Theme Specific Trainings                    |                     9 |       3000000 |
| 2021-22   | Theme Specific Trainings                    |                     9 |       5000000 |
| 2021-22   | Outsource T-Desk                            |                     6 |         61875 |
| 2021-22   | Outsource T-Desk                            |                     6 |        185625 |
| 2021-22   | Outsource T-Desk                            |                     6 |        371250 |
| 2021-22   | Outsource T-Desk                            |                     6 |        618750 |
| 2021-22   | Sector Specific Trainings- One Day          |                    14 |        404250 |
| 2021-22   | Sector Specific Trainings- One Day          |                    14 |       4042500 |
| 2021-22   | Sector Specific Trainings- One Day          |                    14 |       1212750 |
| 2021-22   | Sector Specific Trainings- One Day          |                    14 |       2425500 |
| 2021-22   | On-premises Training Program - Three Day    |                    16 |       3900000 |
| 2021-22   | On-premises Training Program - Three Day    |                    16 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | On-premises Training Program - Three Day    |                    16 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | On-premises Training Program - Three Day    |                    16 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | On-premises Training Program - One Day      |                    10 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | On-premises Training Program - One Day      |                    10 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | On-premises Training Program - One Day      |                    10 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | On-premises Training Program - One Day      |                    10 |       2795000 |
| 2021-22   | In-House Training Program - Physical        |                     1 |       2080000 |
| 2021-22   | In-House Training Program - Physical        |                     1 |        754000 |
| 2021-22   | In-House Training Program - Physical        |                     1 |        546000 |
| 2021-22   | In-House Training Program - Physical        |                     1 |        364000 |
| 2021-22   | In-house Certification                      |                    11 |       1980000 |
| 2021-22   | In-house Certification                      |                    11 |        108000 |
| 2021-22   | In-house Certification                      |                    11 |         72000 |
| 2021-22   | In-house Certification                      |                    11 |         36000 |
| 2021-22   | iBDSP Certification                         |                    13 |       1800000 |
| 2021-22   | iBDSP Certification                         |                    13 |       1080000 |
| 2021-22   | iBDSP Certification                         |                    13 |        540000 |
| 2021-22   | iBDSP Certification                         |                    13 |        180000 |
| 2021-22   | Training of Trainers (TOT) / BDSP Trainings |                     7 |       1200000 |
| 2021-22   | Training of Trainers (TOT) / BDSP Trainings |                     7 |       1600000 |
| 2021-22   | Training of Trainers (TOT) / BDSP Trainings |                     7 |       3200000 |
| 2021-22   | Training of Trainers (TOT) / BDSP Trainings |                     7 |       2000000 |
| 2021-22   | Inhouse T-Desk Online                       |                     4 |        300000 |
| 2021-22   | Youth Entrepreneurship Program              |                     2 |         40000 |
| 2021-22   | In-House Training Program - Online          |                     8 |         75000 |
| 2021-22   | In-House Training Program - Online          |                     8 |         62500 |
| 2021-22   | In-House Training Program - Online          |                     8 |         37500 |
| 2021-22   | Learning Management System Training         |                    12 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | Learning Management System Training         |                    12 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | Learning Management System Training         |                    12 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | Learning Management System Training         |                    12 |             0 |
| 2021-22   | Youth Entrepreneurship Program              |                     2 |        210000 |
| 2021-22   | Youth Entrepreneurship Program              |                     2 |         80000 |
| 2021-22   | Youth Entrepreneurship Program              |                     2 |         60000 |
| 2021-22   | In-House Training Program - Online          |                     8 |        200000 |
| 2021-22   | Inhouse T-Desk Online                       |                     4 |        130000 |
| 2021-22   | Inhouse T-Desk Online                       |                     4 |        100000 |
| 2021-22   | Inhouse T-Desk Online                       |                     4 |         50000 |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: The table contains multiple rows with the same `trai_activity_type` value. When there are multiple values, which one do you want to return - and why?

Comment: I want that function to return all values against the particular trai_activity_type when i give input @SOS

Comment: A mysql function can only return 1 value.. Perhaps a procedure would be appropriate.